# d3v4: Selecting a brush handle breaks brush functionality

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I'm attempting to add some custom functionality to a brushY. **The goal is to have the extents of the brush displayed as text just above/below its respective handles.** To achieve this, I'm selecting the handles `[$n, $s] = [$brush.select(".handle--n"), $brush.select(".handle--s")]` to get their respective y attributes for use with the positioning of the text.

However, I've found that **by selecting the handles**, the **functionality of the brush goes a muck**... *You lose the ability to drag from the handles, their width is reduced, and both handles are positioned to the top of the brush along side one another, instead of their regular north/south positions.*

Can anyone explain **why a simple selection would cause this kind of DOM mutation?**

Relevant code:

```js
private plotBrushText($: d3Selection): d3Selection {
  const $brushHandleText = $.append("g").attr("class", "handle-text");
  $brushHandleText.append("text").attr("class", "handle-text--n");
  $brushHandleText.append("text").attr("class", "handle-text--s");
}

private updateBrushText(col: INumericalColumn): void {
  const [upperBound, lowerBound] = col.state.extents;
  const $col = d3.select(`[id="${col.name}"]`),
    $brush = $col.select(".brush"),
    $ticks = $col.selectAll(".tick"),
    //[$n, $s] = [$brush.select(".handle--n"), $brush.select(".handle--s")],
    //[nY, sY] = [attrY($n), attrY($s)],
    [nY, sY] = [120, 100],
    hideIf = x => x ? "hidden" : null,
    diffLessThan10 = fp.diff(nY, sY) < 10,
    updateText = (sel: string, y: number, txt: number) => $col.select(sel)
    .attr("y", y)
    .attr("x", $ticks.select("text").attr("x"))
    .text(txt.toFixed(2))
    .attr("visibility", hideIf(diffLessThan10));

  updateText(".handle-text--n", nY + 7, upperBound);
  updateText(".handle-text--s", sY - 7, lowerBound);
  $ticks.transition().duration(300).attr("visibility", hideIf(!diffLessThan10));
}

private plotColumns(columns: IColumn[]): d3Selection {
  return this.$$.selectAll(".column")
    .data(columns)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("id", c => c.name)
    .attr("class", c => `${c.type.toLowerCase()} column axis`)
    .attr("transform", c => `translate(${this.xScale(c.name)})`)
    .each(function(col: IColumn) {
      d3.select(this).call(d3.axisLeft(col.scale));
    }).call(this.plotBrushes.bind(this))
    .call(this.plotBrushText) // < -- Relevant code
    .call(this.plotAxisMenus.bind(this))
    .call(this.bindTickEvents.bind(this));
}

private createColumnBrushYGenerator(_objMethods): Brush {
  const {
    updatePathVisibility,
    fg,
    updateBrushText,
    updateExtentState,
    brushStart,
    _size
  } = _objMethods;

  return d3.brushY()
    .extent([
      [-8, 0],
      [8, _size.h]
    ])
    .on("start", brushStart)
    .on("brush", function(col) {
      updateExtentState(col);
      updateBrushText(col); // < -- Relevant code
      updatePathVisibility(fg);
    });
}
```

Notice I have commented out the selection, when the selection does not occur, the brush works as expected.

Below are images with/without the selection being made of the DOM and their respective visual elements

*DOM when selection has been made. Note the y attribute of the brush handles are both equal, they should not be. The width of the handles have also been reduced.*
[image: DOM when selection has been made. Note the y attribute of the brush handles are both equal, they should not be. The width of the handles have also been reduced.]
*DOM without selection. Note the y attributes of the brush handles are correct in this instance, differing by the height attribute of the selection rect element* 
[image: DOM without selection. Note the y attributes of the brush handles are correct in this instance, differing by the height attribute of the selection rect element]

[image: Visual brush elements when selection has been made]
[image: Visual brush elements without selection]

Comment: I found a solution to my endgoal. 

d3.event.selection contains a tuple similar to selecting the brush handles to get their y attributes. Using this instead allowed me to implement the feature. 

However, this does not answer the question of... "why a simple selection would cause this kind of DOM mutation".